# Counterfactuals on philosophy.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

One of the mods [said something](http://%20https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41981/has-anyone-argued-that-what-caused-the-problems-in-the-ussr-would-have-been-simi?noredirect=1#comment105253_41981) I found curious

> Migrated to History, but now that I think about it maybe
>   counter-factual really isn't appropriate anywhere on SE -- outside
>   possibly worldbuilding?

I get the phrase, but don't really know how to understand it. Can we not ask questions about counter-factuals, about e.g. science, or history?

It seems obvious that questions can *include* counterfactuals, if discussing laws of nature, we might want to refer to and illustarte "counterfactuals". Even if they can't be asking for one.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's an interesting question! --The obvious issue is one of effectively unlimited subjectivity, and questionable epistemology of events that never took place in our universe. The metaphysics/epistemological questions about the *notion* of counterfactuals are clearly fine/on-topic; but open-ended speculation on alternative history seems firmly in the worldbuilding space.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by "open ended" or "worldbuilding space" especially ?

Comment: Worldbuilding is a reference to the SE site here http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Open-ended" just means that there's not an obviously correct answer, so maybe not a good fit for SE given the format (i.e., questions have "one correct" answer)

Comment: hmm well i would disagree that a site that seems to be dedicated to creating entirely fictional and imaginary worlds is the right fit for a question asking *would X have happened if not for Y* (at least assuming that we're not asking about a fictional Y)

Comment: Why not exactly? --This is sort of the epistemological issue I'm getting at above, and why there's not a "single correct" answer -- since clearly these alternate events didn't happen in the "real" universe...?

Comment: uhh i think you're over thinking this by talking about 'epistemology' in that context. i would sympathise a little for scientific counterfactuals, which suggests that alternate histories may likewise be "worldbuilding". but as well as being asked not to illustarte a philosophical idea, but to clarify it, there is a sense in which history is different -- it is not listed on site blurb, which may not be an oversite "writers/artists using science, geography and culture"

Comment: i think it is a philosophical point -- whether marxism can lead to "barbarism", at least if marxism is a philosophy

Comment: my counterfactual just isn't fictonal in the same sense as "How effective would an army of succubi have been in medieval times?"

Comment: hm yeah i *definitely* disagree. even if the problem with a **historical** counterfactual asked about a **philosophical** school and **not to write fiction** is that it could generate any kind of answer, perhaps because history is just one event after another, this doesn't apply here, because i specifically ask for events comparable to the stalinist purges etc.. tho obvious you are a mod, and i have no means to challenge the deletion thing

Comment: i've had my account terminated -- weird, i guess cos of the downvotes from history.stackexchange?